# Run jquery after foundation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I have a rails app and i use zurb foundation with it.

I was wondering if it was possible to run my jquery code after foundation's javascript runs its code?

Right now, if for example I write `alert('hello')` after `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` the alert saying hello shows before any of the foundation jquery functions.

I thought this could be achieved by writing`//= require foundation` before `//= require_tree .` but that didnt work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(function(){...});` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. It binds statements to execute once the page has loaded. It doesn't execute the code; it just sets it up to execute later.

If you want the `alert` to happen afterwards, place it afterwards in the binding statement.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
    alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to touch the `require`.

Usually you Just write the code you need after foundation initializing.

Post an example of your foundation functions